# Assigning a delegate to a control

Tags: c#, delegates

I am attempting to bind a method to the click event of a button.

```
var controlEvent = button.GetType().GetEvent("Click");
var eventMethod = GetType().GetMethod("button_Click");
var handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(controlEvent.EventHandlerType, button, eventMethod);

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

When I call CreateDelegate I get

```
Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type
```

I feel like I am passing the wrong types into CreateDelegate but am unsure exactly.

Comment: Any reason you're doing this with reflection?

Comment: No. is there a better way?

Comment: @Julien: Is there a better way to do _what_? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: well when @GeorgeMauer said doing "this", i assumed (incorrectly) that he meant assigning a delegate dynamically to a control

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use reflection here. Been a while since I've worked with winforms/webforms but it should look something like this:

```
button.OnClick += button_Click;
```

I'll comment further that `button_Click` is not a good name for a method unless what it does is click a button. That convention comes from some really old Microsoft guidance and it's just not good. Name functions after what they do, not how they're used. Consider how much better this reads

```
button.OnClick += showCalculations;
```

I usually go a step further and get rid of the dumb `(object, EventArgs)` parameters as well (unless I'm using these)

```
button.OnClick += (o,e) => showCalculations();
//...
void showCalculations() {
   //...
}
```

Comment: I misunderstood your comment. I need to find methods by string at runtime.

Comment: people can write scripts that get read in on form load and add/alter behavior

Comment: Then have the statically bound event handler function differently based on the program's data, rather than dynamically binding the event handler.

Comment: @Julien then they would be able to script your application to call *any* method on the class, including ones you didn't intend for them to call. What about storing the delegates you *do* want them to have access to in a dictionary and picking the right one out of there?

Comment: at the moment there is no issue with allowing full access. I can certainly go down that road if we decide to restrict the events they have access to

Comment: @Julien so do you not plan to extract private methods when code gets overly complex? I understand YAGNI but you **will** need that, and if at that point your options are to write messy code or re-architect the whole thing you're going to choose messy code. This is an obvious case where you should avoid yourself the trouble.

Comment: why do you assume I will need that? this is a customers application, they can script it however they like.

Comment: Simply because *extract private method*, is only behind *rename* as the most useful and ubiquitous refactoring. I use it many times a day. I'm still not understanding your architecture though, you say people can script this, but your code is in c# which is not a scripting language. Can you edit the question with details on your architecture?

Comment: Using ClearScript. There are forms, that have controls, that we can script events onto.  So for eg a TextBox has a custom TextChanged event that pops up a messagebox. You can even add controls to an existing form at runtime.

Comment: @Julien I see, Edit the title on this post to something like "dynamically creating event delegates", tag it with reflection, and maybe explain that in the post itself

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `Delegate.CreateDelegate` is the class instance to call the method on.

Your method isn't defined on `button`, so you get an error.
You need to pass `this`.